# python image resize で品質を落とさない方法

Tags: python, 画像, pillow

お世話になります。
掲題の件で、画像をリサイズ（比率を保持して縮小する）後、画質が荒くなってしまいます。
pillowを使って以下の通りにしていますが、何か別のやり方等ご教示いただければ幸いです。

```
# original file size (1000, 3000)

from PIL import Image
imagePil = Image.open(file)
imagePil = imagePil.resize((100,300), resample=Image.LANCZOS)
imagePil.save(fileName, quality=95, dpi=(600,600))
```

やりたいことは元画像のサムネイルサイズに縮小し、エクセルの指定幅のセルに表示したいのがやりたいことです。

単純にサイズを落とさず、縮小したものをエクセルに添付できればOKなんですが。。

Comment: 参考までに、元画像のファイル形式の情報もあるとよいかもしれません。

Comment: 失礼しました、PNG形式の画像となります。

Comment: 出来上がるEXCELファイルのサイズが大きくなり、表示品質もEXCELまかせになりますが、EXCEL自身の縮小表示機能を使うとか。[エクセル2010基本講座：図(写真や画像)を挿入する](http://www4.synapse.ne.jp/yone/excel2010/excel2010_zu_sounyu.html)、[エクセルの写真挿入時に「図の挿入」から挿入しています。 その際、元の写真データのピクセル数に関係なく自分が指定した大きさに設定し自動縮小や拡大して挿入する方法を教えてくだ](https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/6259011.html)、[1380: エクセルシートに写真を挿入し、クリックし拡大表示させたい](http://blog.canpan.info/pctech/archive/1389)、[Shapes. AddPicture メソッド (Excel)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/api/excel.shapes.addpicture)

Comment: ありがとうございます！画像縮小から貼り付けまでpythonで完結させようと思っていましたが、マクロで対応してみたいと思います。